# mask object spline points coordinates

Tags: python, scripting, export

I'm trying to export mask spline points x and y data by using:

```
bpy.data.masks['Mask'].layers['0'].splines[0].points[0].co
```

but i get an x, y vector with an unknown coordinates like:

```
(0.40345168113708496, 0.4609205424785614)
```

i think they are a percentage of the image i made the mask on, i need to convert it to pixel format where it should show something like:

```
(402,503)
```

i tried to do some math, and multiplied it with image the resolution, but the resulting numbers are wrong!
i do not get the formula behind this vector after searching many posts, can some please point me to it or how to convert it to image space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strangely enough, Blender calculates the relativ dimensions with respect to the larger dimension.
These words are not very well choosen. Here is a graphic that show a large orange square. Blender gives us relativ coordinates in this reference frame. The green rectangle is our movie aspect ratio.

[image: graphic]

```
import bpy

render = bpy.context.scene.render

coordinate = bpy.data.masks[0].layers[0].splines[0].points[0].co.copy()
coordinate.x *= render.resolution_x
coordinate.y = coordinate.y * render.resolution_x - (render.resolution_x - render.resolution_y) / 2

# at 100%, this gives us the correct coordinate
print(coordinate)
```

Comment: thanks this is the math i was looking for, it worked but it is flipped on the y axis!

Comment: please see this illustration this https://imgur.com/a/5QHucjD

Comment: okay i fixed it by using co_y = res_y - co_y